# What is .asar file and why it's used in electron applications

Tags: electron, asar

So the question is in the title. As far as I understand, .asar is kind of archived file using in electron app. But what is the goal for it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Asar is used to concatenate your application files to one big file, it mitigates issues and it slightly speeds up **require**.

> To mitigate issues around long path names on Windows, slightly speed
> up require and conceal your source code from cursory inspection, you
> can choose to package your app into an asar archive with little
> changes to your source code.

[web archive of original URL](http://web.archive.org/web/20170412010217/https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/application-packaging.md) [Electron en ebook](https://electron.ebookchain.org/en/tutorial/application-packaging.html)