# Electron JS App still has default Icons (.appx file built with electron-windows-store)

Tags: javascript, windows, powershell, electron, appx

I've tried every solution I could find online but the logo keeps defaulting to electron logo. I do see my logos in the pre-appx/assets folder alongside the default Sample*.png files.

This is the command I use to build the appx file:

```
electron-windows-store --input-directory C:\nukleus-online-desktop-app\win-unpacked --output-directory C:\ --package-version 1.0.0.0 --package-name 'NukleusAanlynApp' --package-display-name 'Nukleus Aanlyn App' --publisher-display-name 'Nukleus Onderwys' --identity-name 31765NukleusOnderwys.NukleusAanlynApp -a C:\nukleus-online-desktop-app\Resources\
```

The logo files are now named only by size:

44x44.png

but I have tried Square44x44.Logo.png and it also did not work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated! I have also checked the repo and there are issues regarding this which seem to be sorted but I found no actual solutions.

Comment: I'm facing this same exact issue

Answer (score 0):

Your files are probably inside the .asar this is an extremely common question from people using external powershell scripts + create-react-app.  Please read [What is .asar file and why it's used in electron applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39478579/what-is-asar-file-and-why-its-used-in-electron-applications)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!

You have two options, rename the icons to the Sample**.png names that are default. This will overrite the default images.

Or,

Use the -m flag in to replace the Manifest file, in which you can rename all the assets to the names you have given the logos.

1. Unpack the .appx file
2. Rename icons or edit Manifest file to rename icons
3. Re-pack and Re-sign .appx file